# <base target = _blank> not working for iFrame in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

In My application on click of a link i open one POPUP window which has one button which opens another POPUP window, which has one Iframe and one dropdown for language. On change of dropdown iFrame body gets changed dynamically like below

```
$('#tncFrame').contents().find('body')[0].innerHTML="<base target='_blank'/>" + $scope.tncFileContent;
```

**$scope.tncFileContent** this is a dynamic html content.

I have prefixed `<base target='_blank'/>` to the html so that links in the dynamic html content open in new window.

IN FF and Chrome its working fine but not in IE. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Did you work this out? @Ashock